# Python put list of int as character numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying that at one point turns a list of integers and turns them into characters, then strings. For example:

```
items = [10, 20, 42]
```

If the three integers 10, 20, and 42 were given, I'd want to do change it into something that works in the sense of:

```
items = [chr(10), chr(20), chr(42)]
print(" ".join(items))
```

or:

```
items = chr(items)
print(" ".join(items))
```

But the second one does not work... and I need a way to do it that works if the number of items on the list is not always the same.

Comment: If you eventually want to print the list as strings then why not set sitems = [str(i) for i in items] so that  print(" ".join(sitems)) prints "10 20 42"?  The same result can be obtained with print(str(items).strip('[]').replace(',', '')).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `chr`

```
''.join(map(chr, items))
```

Answer (score 1):

You easily use comprehension like this one:

```
" ".join(chr(x) for x in items)
```